# Prove that $M$ is flat $\iff$ each $M_i$ is flat (2.4 Atiyah & MacDonald pg. 31)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, flatness

Here is the question I want to solve:

Let $M_i (i \in I)$ be any family of $A$-modules, let $M$ be their direct sum. Prove that $M$ is flat $\iff$ each $M_i$ is flat.

Here is a solution to it found on the internet:

> [image]

But I do not understand the following:

1-Why we need to identify $j \otimes id_M$ with a map $h$? also, what criteria should we  use for choosing this map?

Here are the isomorphisms of (2.14 iii*):

> [image]

And here is (2.22.i*):

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The takeaway of Proposition 2.22 is that exactness can be checked *coordinate wise*, in the sense that if a short sequence $\mathsf S: 0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$ of morphisms is obtained by taking the direct sum of several short sequences of morphisms $0\to M_i'\to M_i\to M_i''\to 0$, then $\mathsf S$ is exact if and only if each summand sequence is itself exact.

Going to the second-to-last claim, this is saying that if one takes a sequence $\mathsf S$ and if $M$ is the sum of modules $M_i$, then $\mathsf S\otimes_ AM$ is the sum of the sequences $\mathsf{S}_i = \mathsf{S}\otimes_A M_i$. This means that  $\mathsf S\otimes_ AM$ is exact if and only if each $\mathsf{S}_i = \mathsf{S}\otimes_A M_i$ is exact by the first paragraph.

Finally, $\mathsf{S}_i = \mathsf{S}\otimes_A M_i$ is exact for *any* $\mathsf{S}$ if and only if $M_i$ is flat (by definition, if you would like to) which means that $\mathsf{S}\otimes_A M$ is exact for any $\mathsf{S}$ if and only if each $M_i$ is flat. Thus $M$ is $A$-flat if and only if each $M_i$ is flat.

The map $h$ is simply the unique map that sends a finite sum $\sum_{i\in I}n_i\otimes m_i$ with $n_i\in N'$ and $m_i\in M_i$ to the finite sum $\sum_{i\in I} j(n_i)\otimes m_i$ where now $j(n_i)\in N$. There is a typo in the solutions and the $N'$ in the codomain should be an $N$. The whole motto of this result is that tensor products commute with direct sums: for any family of modules $\{M_i : i\in I\}$ and any module $N$, there is a natural isomorphism

$$ M\otimes N  \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i\otimes N 
$$

where $M = \left(\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i\right)$ that sends an element  $m\otimes n$ with $m = \sum_{i\in I} m_i $ to $\sum_{i\in I} m_i\otimes n$. The inverse map sends an element $\sum_{i\in I} m_i\otimes n_i$ to the the sum $\sum_{i\in I} m_ie_i\otimes n_i$ where $m_ie_i\in M$ is the element that is zero everywhere except on the $i$th coordinate where it equals $m_i$.

Comment: but in your second paragraph you are speaking about tensor products(not sequences in the sense of short exact sequences), why you are using the word "exact"?

Comment: In your third paragraph, when you said "(by definition, if you would like to)" which definition are you referring to, I am looking only to proposition 2.19(ii), are you speaking about this? again I am not seeing any exact sequence, I am just seeing tensor product of 2 modules

Comment: So, in general what criteria from proposition 2.19 is used in the proof, is it 2.19(iii)? ..... I see you were speaking previously(if I understand correctly) about 2.19(ii)

Comment: A good reference is Bourbaki's 'Commutative Algebra' first chapter "Flat Modules". In particular $\S 2$, no.3 Proposition 2, which is the result in your question.

Comment: I looked at it, but I did not get the meaning of exact homomorphisms. do they mean when we put them in an exact sequence, the sequence will be exact? @P.Lawrence

Comment: I do not understand this statement "if a short sequence $\mathsf S: 0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$ of morphisms is obtained by taking the direct sum of several short sequences of morphisms $0\to M_i'\to M_i\to M_i''\to 0$,". do you mean, if for example, the indexing set $I = \{1,2\}.$ then the sequence $\mathsf S: 0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$ is equal to the sequence $$0\to M_1'\to M_1\to M_i''\to 0 \oplus  0\to M_2'\to M_2\to M_2''\to 0$$? but what does it mean to direct sum 2 exact sequences? or we are directing sum the modules and the morphisms?